# How do I fix Laravel Composer autoload_classmap Error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I've downloaded our copy of a Laravel project to my local computer. I'm running XAMP 3.2.2, PHP 5.6.19.  I've installed Composer and updated the database configuration.

But as I run the project, localhost/AAAAA (AAAAA is the folder of the Laravel project), I get the error below:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' => $vendorDir . '' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\AAAAA\vendor\composer\autoload_classmap.php on line 1621
```

How do I fix the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Did the laravel downloaded completely ? It shows any error in the composer while installing ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try regenerating the composer autoload files:

```
php composer.phar dump-autoload
```

Since you just downloaded the project, you'd likely need to initiate an install first which should do this for you:

```
php composer.phar install
```

The install command will install all project dependencies into vendor/ and dump the autoload files. The package information is stored in composer.json & composer.lock.